# JSF `action` not executed if javascript confirmation box used?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using jsf PrimeFaces (v 3.5.0) library. 
The following code doesn't execute `delete` after javascript confirmation box `OK` button is selected.

```
<p:commandLink id="deletePGLinkId"
    action="#{PresetGroupMgmtBean.delete}"
    onclick="return confirm('Preset Group will be removed. Are you sure you want to continue?');"
    update=":pmForm:presetPanel :pmForm:messagePanel">
      <f:param value="#{item.value.ID}" name="deleteID"></f:param>
      <h:graphicImage alt="Delete Image" style="border: none" value="./images/x.png" />  
</p:commandLink>
```

I'd like to avoid using PrimeFaces `ConfirmDialog` since I have so many confirmations, and it will take time to write a `ConfirmDialog` for each. Javascript box seems easy, but it doesn't work.

Why doesn't it execute `delete`?

Comment: Working for me on Firefox 22, looks more like a JSF error, is your code working if you remove the `confirm` ?

Comment: @landal: sorry, but that is true nonsense.

Comment: @Alexandre: which PF version? This bug is at least present in 3.5 and before.

Comment: @BalusC I'm using the PrimeFaces 3.5 but actually searching if it is 3.5.X

Comment: No, a simple 3.5 version, the jar is primefaces-3.5.jar... I notice the `onclick="return confirm('Sure?');;PrimeFaces.ab({source:'formId:linkId'});return false;"` but it is working properly.

Comment: @Alexandre: Isn't that just misobservation? With "it" you mean the command link action method, right?

Comment: @BalusC I was testing with a `p:commandButton` which is not the good one, but kindly strange that it is working properly since the JavaScript `onclick` rendered code is exactly the same as the `p:commandLink`. A HTML link doesn't handle the same as a button?

Comment: @Alexandre: it will just degrade to synchronous (non-ajax!) action as it generates an `<input type="submit">` element whose default behavior is synchronously submitting the parent form. It'll thus behave as if JavaScript is disabled. In other words, the `PrimeFaces.ab()` is also never invoked! You can confirm this behavior by just looking at JS debugger and HTTP traffic monitor.

Comment: @BalusC sorry, I've done bad cut and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat a design bug in PrimeFaces command link renderer. Look closer in the generated HTML output:

```
onclick="return confirm('Sure?');;PrimeFaces.ab({source:'formId:linkId'});return false;"
```

Do you see it now? The `PrimeFaces.ab()` who's responsible for submitting the form will this way *never* be invoked! You'd need to write the condition differently:

```
onclick="if (!confirm('Sure?')) return false;"
```

this way the HTML will ultimately be generated like follows:

```
onclick="if (!confirm('Sure?')) return false;;PrimeFaces.ab({source:'formId:linkId'});return false;"
```

this way it will properly continue to `PrimeFaces.ab()` when `confirm()` has returned `true` (it will then not invoke the `return false;` statement).

Mojarra uses `jsf.util.chain()` for this. Replace `<p:commandLink>` by `<h:commandLink>` and you'll see it in the generated HTML output:

```
onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'return confirm(\'Sure?\');','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'formId\'),{\'formId:linkId\':\'formId:linkId\'},\'\')');return false"
```

This way your initial construct would have worked.

Comment: Works, thanks very much. I in fact had this line that didn't work: `onclick="if( confirm('Location will be removed. Are you sure you want to continue?') ){return true;}else{return false;}"`. After your suggestion, this works: `onclick="if( !confirm('Location will be removed. Are you sure you want to continue?') ){return false;}"`.

Comment: One more problem: I used to execute block UI `bui()` when `OK` is selected: `onclick="if( confirm('Location will be removed. Are you sure you want to continue?') ){bui.show();return true;}else{return false;}"`. Seems not to be possible any more?

Comment: You should in no way return true. Returning from onclick prevents the remainder of onclick code from being invoked. Use this: `onclick="if (!confirm('Sure?')) return false; bui.show();"`. Alternatively, put `bui.show()` in `onstart`.

Comment: OK, `onstart="bui.show()` works. That resolved it all, thanks.